How to find the probability that no two hockey players are standing together
A school has $n$ pupils,
of whom $r$ play hocket,
where $n\geqslant r\geqslant2$.
All $n$ pupils are arranged in a row at random.
(i)
What is the probability that there is a hockey player at each end of the row?
(ii)
What is the probability that all the hockey players are standing together?
(iiii)
By considering the gaps between the non--hockey players,
find the probability that no two hockey players are standing together,
distinguishing between cases
when the probability is zero and when it is non--zero.
Main issue is that for (iii), one proposed solution is
Line up our non-hockey players.
They leave $(n-r+1)$ "slots" to put hockey players in (one player per slot).
We can arrange this in ${ n-r+1 \choose r} \times r!$ ways.
Therefore our probability is:
$$
 \frac{ {n-r+1 \choose r} r!}{n!} 
 = 
 \frac{(n-r+1)!r!}{n!r!(n-r+1-r)!} 
 =
 \boxed{\frac{(n-r+1)!}{n!(n-2r+1)!}}
$$
But my thoughts are
$$
 \frac{ (n-r)! {}^{n-r+1}P_r }{n!}
 =
 \frac{ (n-r)! }{n!} \times \frac{ (n-r+1)!}{(n-r+1-r)!}
 =
 \frac{ (n-r)! (n-r+1)! }{ n! (n+1-2r)! }
$$
The only difference is that, the proposed treats this as a Combination problem, while as I think since the denominator is $n!$, we should use arrangement instead.
Can someone clarify this a bit, or was the question not so clear as what it was asking?

Please type your question rather than posting an image because images cannot be searched and may not be readable by users who rely on screen readers.

@N.F.Taussig Just edited the question a bit with latex as required.

Your answer is correct.  The proposed answer in the text is incorrect because the author fails to arrange the non-hockey players.
There are $(n - r)!$ ways to arrange the non-hockey players in a row.  Doing so creates $n - r + 1$ spaces in which to place the $r$ hockey players, $n - r - 1$ spaces between successive non-hockey players and two at the ends of the row.  There are $\binom{n - r + 1}{r}$ ways to select spaces for the hockey players so that no two of them are adjacent and $r!$ ways to arrange them in the selected spaces.  Since there are $n!$ ways to arrange all $n$ pupils, the probability that no two hockey players are adjacent is
$$\frac{(n - r)!\binom{n - r + 1}{r}r!}{n!} = \frac{(n - r)! \cdot \frac{(n - r + 1)!}{r!(n - 2r + 1)!} \cdot r!}{n!} = \frac{(n - r)!(n - r + 1)!}{n!(n - 2r + 1)!}$$
as you found. The probability is equal to zero unless $n - r + 1 \geq r$.  To get a non-zero probability, we require that $n \geq 2r - 1$.

Great! This is an old STEP question back in 1995, with no official markscheme now. Only some "random" posts of answers online. I was not sure if I understood the question correctly. Thanks for the confirmation.

Hi @Taussig. I instead came up with  $\frac{(n - r)!(n - r + 1) r!}{n!}$, with the rationale being there's $(n-r+1)$ ways to pick a 'slot' in which to start arranging the $r$ hockey players contiguously. I don't get why it would be $\binom{n - r + 1}{r}$.

@droptop We must separate the $r$ hockey players so that no two of them are adjacent.  Therefore, we need to ensure that there is at least one non-hockey player between any two hockey players.  We can do this by placing hockey players in the $n - r -  1$ spaces between two successive non-hockey players or by placing a hockey player at one of the two ends of the row.  Therefore, there are $n - r - 1 + 2 = n - r + 1$ spaces in which we can place the $r$ hockey players.  The number of ways we can select $r$ of these spaces in which to place the $r$ hockey players is $\binom{n - r + 1}{r}$.

Oh excuse my carelessness. I thought you were answering (ii)
